# Facebook open graph localization for share button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I'm trying to setup localized og meta tags for my website so when users share it will display in en-US (Default) or fr-CA. I've structured the meta tags in my view  like:

```
@if (Model.Culture.ToLower() == "fr-ca" || Model.ShowFrenchOgTags)
{
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="SITENAME" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="fr_CA" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_CA" />

    <meta property="og:title" content="French Title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="French Description" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://url" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://urltoimage.jpg" />
    <meta property = "og:image:secure_url" content = "https://urltoimage.jpg" />
}
else
{
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="SITENAME" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_CA" />

    <meta property="og:title" content="English Title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="English Description" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://url" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://urltoimage.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://urltoimage.jpg" />
}
```

and I'm setting the properties of Model.Culture and Model.ShowFrenchOgTags in my controller like:

```
public ActionResult FacebookShare()
    {
        var model = new DevViewModel();
        model.Culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;

        if ((Request.QueryString["fb_locale"] != null && Request.QueryString["fb_locale"].ToLower() == "fr_ca")
            || (Request.QueryString["locale"] != null && Request.QueryString["locale"].ToLower() == "fr_ca")
            || (Request.Headers["X-Facebook-Locale"] != null && Request.Headers["X-Facebook-Locale"].ToLower().Trim() == "fr_ca"))
        {
            model.ShowFrenchOgTags = true;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

for some reason when I use the facebook open graph debugger it only returns the English content even when I click on one of the language links in the parsed response. Is there something that I'm missing to get the different languages to display?

Comment: Localization does not work for links shared in normal wall posts, it only works for Open Graph stories.

Comment: is it possible to have the dialog for share_open_graph look like the share dialog where the image is on top of the copy not beside?

Comment: Don’t know. But that won’t help you with this issue either – unless you completely switch to Open Graph Stories, but then you need to have a valid _action_ for your story as well.